# How do I build a batch file that will copy the newest files for particular naming convention

Tags: batch-file, find, copy

I am stuck trying to build a batch file that will copy the newest files for particular naming conventions from a folder containing multiple naming conventions. For example the folder would contain the following types of file name, and i want the newest List01 and the newest List02:

```
C:\Import\List01####.txt    modified date 01/07/2021 15:40
C:\Import\List01####.txt    modified date 02/07/2021 15:40
C:\Import\List02####.txt    modified date 03/07/2021 15:40
C:\Import\List02####.txt    modified date 04/07/2021 15:40
```

the #### represents any random naming, the important bit is the List01 or List02 etc

I want the output to be a copy of the newest file for each list number:

```
C:\Results\List01####.txt   modified date 02/07/2021 15:40
C:\Results\List02####.txt   modified date 04/07/2021 15:40
```

So far I have the following that will find the newest file in the folder, but I'm not sure how to make it distinguish between List01 and List02 as I need the newest file of each list. I've tried findstr but can't get it to work.

```
@echo off
set source="C:\Import\"
set target="C:\Results"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('DIR %source%\*.txt /A:-D /O:-D /B') DO COPY %source%\"%%I" %target% & echo %%I & GOTO :END

TIMEOUT 5

:END
```

I have read a similar post about this but couldn't figure out how to apply it to my specific situation.

Comment: Replace `*.txt` with `List01*.txt` and add another line for `List2`. Or use another loop around to take care of `01`, `02` (and more, if needed).

Comment: Perfect, thanks. A simple that works :)